# How to get the string name of the argument's type hint?

Tags: php, function, types

Let us say we have this function:

```
function greetMe (string $name) {                                                                                                                                        
    echo '<br/>'.$name;                                                                                                                                                  
    echo '<br/>'.gettype($name);                                                                                                                                         
}
```

As you can see, we can get the type of the parameter `$name`.
Now I am interested to know if there is a possibility, within the body of this function, to know that I declared the type `string` and not some other type. Any hints?

Comment: isn't `gettype`'s what you're looking for, you already have it there

Comment: No, I am not looking for `gettype($argument)`, I want to be able to access the type `string` instead (I am in a situation where I need this information for a specific need)

Comment: @Ghost Consider the case `function greetMe(Foo $foo)` with a `class Bar extends  Foo` where the function is used as `greetMe(aBar)`. Then, `gettype` would return `Bar` even though the type hint is `Foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP 7 and later, you can use [`ReflectionParameter.getType`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.gettype.php).

> Example #1 ReflectionParameter::getType() example
>
> ```
> <?php
> function someFunction(int $param, $param2) {}
>
> $reflectionFunc = new ReflectionFunction('someFunction');
> $reflectionParams = $reflectionFunc->getParameters();
> $reflectionType1 = $reflectionParams[0]->getType();
> $reflectionType2 = $reflectionParams[1]->getType();
>
> echo $reflectionType1;
> var_dump($reflectionType2);
> ```
>
> The above example will output something similar to:
>
> ```
> int
> null
> ```

Comment: That is exactly what I need. Merci.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ you mean something like this? https://3v4l.org/Vnf5E just googled it, and it was readily available (well not the answer but the reflection class itself)

Comment: Yes, the `ReflectionParameter.getType` is the key answer to my problem, thank you @Ghost

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ sure glad this shed some light, don't forget to accept vulcan's answer